# How to take input in Python in SPOJ problem COINS?

Tags: python, algorithm, input, implementation

Can anyone help me how to take input described in the problem below (link provided). I just want to know the implementation of the input part in Python 3.7 language. Please don't share your answer or logic of the main problem.

https://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
        value = int(input()) # Bytelandian coins can only have integer values.
    except:
        break
    # your code to find and print the dollars you can make for a coin worth 'value' goes here
    ...
```